# Loop over the links of an API response

Tags: python, api, get, response

I am working with an API which response is structured as follows:

> ```
> {'_links': {'_self': 'https://api.....',
>   'next': 'https://api.....?page_marker=2023-04-05'},
>  'results': [{'name': 'first_result'}, {'...': '...'}]
> ```

What I want to do is:

- Count the length of `results` on this first page
- Go to the next one using the `next` link
- Count the length of results on this second page
- Keep going until there is no furhter `next` link

The objective is to know the full lenght of `results` as they come paginated in the API.

I have tried so far with a `while` loop:

```
total_results = len(results_list.json()['results'])

results = results_list.json()['results']

while results_list.json()['_links']['next']:
    next_url = results_list.json()['_links']['next']
    next_response = session.get(next_url)
    total_results += len(next_response.json()['results'])
    results.extend(results_list.json()['results'])
```

Seems logic to me but I end up with this error:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Any clue on what am I missing?

Comment: What is the value of `next` when there is no next page? Is it None? Or does `next` not exist in the JSON? In this case, the `JSONDecodeError` could be raised because of the non-existence of the `next` line.

Comment: indeed, when i go the the last page,  `{links:  }` only contains `_self`. Is that the origin of my error? How to work around that in a clean way? Capture the error and use it to break the loop?

Comment: Oh then you could change `while results_list.json()['_links']['next']` into `while 'next' in results_list.json()['_links']`

Comment: So, running that I get the error `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
`

Comment: What line raises the error?

Comment: This one: `total_results += len(next_response.json()['results'])`

Comment: Maybe print `next_response.json()` to see if it has a `results` attribute. I like debbuging like this to make out parts that work for sure and others that don't. Seems like a problem with your JSON to me, not your code.

Comment: mm got a 429 error code, which in the documentation says a rate limit has been exceeded. They suggest implementing retry with an exponential backoff. Does taht mean puting a hold for 1 sec for example?

Comment: I guess so, but the problem comes from the way you get all the links. You should change the way the links are stored if possible, for example if you plan on executing this code more than once.